# are there DOM events for controller presses on the PS3?

Tags: dom, playstation3, playstation

I want to develop a site which is easy to use from a Playstation 3 PS3 game console web browser. I thought it would be good to make screen actions on button presses on the console.

I can find no information on how to do this after quite a bit of searching.

Any info or links highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Why not write a function that displays a message for every "keystroke" and you'll see what values they represent:

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
   alert(event.which);
});
```

Then you can use the number you get from this test and create some logic based on that.

Like this perhaps:

```
if(event.which == 13) {
    // display cool menu maybe?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I've tested so far, the left stick generates mouse events, left pad with arrows generates keyboard events corresponding to arrows, while the right stick generates a mouseevent but unfortunately it does not move the mouse, but rather scrolls the window.
I do not know how to detect in which direction the stick is pushed (unless the cursor actually moved or the background scrolled, in which cases it is quite trivial).

Check: http://vanisoft.pl/~lopuszanski/public/ps3/